# Integer Overflow klocwork analysis

Tags: java, integer-overflow, klocwork

I have the following lines of code and when I run klocwork analysis on my project I get the following error

**SV.INT_OVF: Tainted data 'Long.parseLong(...)' that comes from 'br.readLine()' is used in an arithmetic operation and can cause an integer overflow or unexpected result**

My code

```
 while (line = br.readLine() != null) {
     long timestamp = timescale * Long.parseLong(line.substring(1, line.length()));
 }
```

How can I refactor this code to avoid possible overflow

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `BigInteger` to avoid an overflow.

Whether you should is another question.

I would look at what is a sane range for these values and validate your inputs first.  Most likely the widest range of sane values won't produce an overflow (or if it does, you have to use BigInteger)